# How to create clone of existing DNN site?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to create Test site of a Production site which is created in DNN, but not successful in doing so. I have copied the whole production DNN folder at the other location and pointed it from IIS, but its not working. It shows NULL reference exception when i try to hit the URL.

Can someone help

Comment: DNN is database driven. You need to copy the files AND the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy all files of your root folder on the production machine to the
   test machine
2. Make a backup of your database on the production
   machine and add it to your test machine
3. Create a new sql user in SSMS on the test machine and add it to the database as dbowner
4. Edit the web.config on the test machine and change the ConnectionString to the new Sql User
5. Add the new site to the IIS with original domain name
6. Edit %windows%/system32/drivers/etc/host and add a line with your domain and the IP-Address 127.0.0.1
7. Edit the extended properties of the application package in IIS and change the identity to "network service"
8. Give wwwroot folder (exact: your website home folder) in windows explorer "full control" access rights for network service

if you want to automate this with powershell scripts -> this blog post could help: http://www.bitboxx.net/Blog/Post/189/Make-a-local-copy-of-your-live-DNN-installation#/